# Read More Post wordpress with js

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

hi i want to add read more with js which will show limited content when some click read more it will show full post on same page

below is the code i am using

```
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php 
                    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                        $paged = get_query_var('page');
                    } else {
                        $paged = 1;
                    }
                    query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post' , 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );
                ?> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post-box img-polaroid row">
<h3 class="title-post text-left span3"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<div class="post-par span6 text-left"><?php the_content();?></div>

 <span class="span3 offset3 text-center" style="width:100%; margin:0px;">
 <button class="hear-more"></button>

</span>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>`
```

when some click read more it will show full post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with php limit post by:

```
$length_limit = 1000; //character
echo '<div class="summaryarticle">';
echo mb_substr(the_content(), 0, $length_limit);
echo '</div>';

echo '<input type="button" value="show more..." onclick="$(this).prev().hide(); $(this).next().show();" />';

echo '<div class="fullarticle" style="display:none">';
echo the_content();
echo '</div>';
```

**notice:** use must include jquery in page. maybe that be.

Comment: hi can you fix there is a error in line 7 echo '<input type="button" value="show more..." onclick="$('#summaryarticle').hide(); $('#fullarticle').show();" />

Comment: get this error Warning: mb_strlen() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in D:\xampp\htdocs\dwell\wp-content\themes\frappin\launch-template.php on line 57

Comment: now full post hide post on click function not working i get this error  Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: hi i edit it with this echo '<input type="button" value="show more..." onclick="jQuery(\'#summaryarticle\').hide(); jQuery(\'#fullarticle\').show();" />'; not its working but it working for one post other post its not working i want it to work with loop recent post

Comment: @SonuMeena agian edited: all `ID`s Changed To `Class` And jquery codes changed!

Comment: last question i want to show hide with same button now it only hide but not get again excerpt post

Comment: its in localhost but here is the code .... <?php

$length_limit = 1000; //character
?>
<div id="summaryarticle-<?= $id ?>">
<?php
echo mb_substr(the_content(), 0, $length_limit);
?>
</div>
 <button style="float:right;" onclick="jQuery('#summaryarticle-<?= $id ?>').hide(); jQuery('#fullarticle-<?= $id ?>').show();" class="hear-more"></button>                                          
<div id="fullarticle-<?= $id ?>" style="display:none">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

Comment: final help new code only hide not get and i want to use this button bellow fullarticle div